# emulator-5554 is not visible on screen?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cmd

[image][image][image]

---

In the Android emulator 5554 is online but it is not visible on screen, but some application is running. so how to solve this problem. In the picture see  `?[2.3.4,debug]` how to make emulator-5554 online or visible on screen. any application start in emulator-5556/5558 but not in emulator-5554

Comment: just delete it, recreate it with the same parameters.

Comment: yes, would that be a problem in your case?

Comment: i already delete all avd but still that problem occurs. my problem is that emulator-5554 is online but it is not visible on the screen

Comment: yes, I can see it's target platform cannot be detected correctly. Maybe you can try and update Android SDK and AVD Manager?

Comment: ok i wil try to update Android SDK and AVD Manager........

Comment: You say this 2 things: "emulator-5554 is online but it is not visible" and "but sill not working ....my emulator is visible." so which on is it?>

Answer (score 19):

If the window is off screen then do the following:
select the task bar item and right-click (shift+right-click on win7)
select Move - use arrows to move LEFT or RIGHT.  If you mouse click you'll have to start over.
once the window magically pops back on screen, then you can move it normally.

Comment: i found this things the solution is that if you installed BlueStacks Cloud Connect this software in your windows 7/xp then it by default your android emulator port no can used this software. Example like--5554....so just uninstalled this software and it will work for me..

Comment: I found this advice after I solved the problem myself. The solution was to launch emulator not from Android Studio, but from AVD Manager. After that even launching from Android Studio resulted in the emulator screen beeing in the center.

Comment: This was the first link when I looked up the problem on Google. I didn't want to re-create the emulator because I knew the parameters were correct. The problem occurred when I was 'extending' my display with a second monitor, so it makes sense why the device would be off-screen, but I couldn't move it using other methods. the Shift+Right-click was very helpful, and the emulator was running and ready for use! This answer should be selected!

Answer (score 2):

If it not visible then just kill the process that is holding that emulator and restart it. On Windows <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to bring up the task manager. One the task manager is up, find the emulator process and kill it.

Comment: When i do CTRL+ALT+DEL to task manager display adb.exe32* that process i will Do End Task But after some minute i will again come back....

Answer (score 1):

Please check your installed programs , there might be some program (eg:bluestack )which runs adb , Uninstall all such program and you will surely find your emulator running.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a little easier in addition to Android Addicts' answer...once you selected move you can just use your mouse (don't click) to move around the emulator window (at least on win7). a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your resolution of the screen then you got the title bar off the emulator .now it is mouse accessible, move emulator in center.now you can change the previous view model.